# Replicate form to print two copies on one sheet vba

Tags: vba, printing

Using form as electronic receipt and want to print two copies on one sheet of paper.  How can I replicate the form on printing?

Comment: Have you tried `File ~> Print`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help.  I wasn't able to use the suggestions--Nicholas you totally got what I was going for--but went with this fairly low-tech solution which works.  By creating a "mock" form on another spreadsheet, I was able to write values from the user form controls to specific cells on the spreadsheet, replicate the mock form below, and thus print two on one page--for two copies of the receipt.  Here is the code I used:

Private Sub PrintCMD_Click()

'Load form values to spreadsheet 2

```
Sheet2.Activate
Range("A1:K16").Select

Range("B3").Value = DateTimeTXT.Value
Range("B5").Value = StrConv(FirstNameTXT.Value, vbUpperCase)
Range("C5").Value = StrConv(LastNameTXT.Value, vbUpperCase)
Range("J5").Value = RelationshipCBO.Value
Range("B7").Value = PaymentType1CBO.Value
Range("B9").Value = Ref1TXT.Value
Range("B11").Value = AmountTXT.Value
Range("B13").Value = ApplyToCBO.Value
Range("F7").Value = PaymentType2CBO.Value
Range("F9").Value = REF2TXT.Value
Range("F11").Value = Amount2TXT.Value
Range("F13").Value = ApplyTo2CBO.Value
Range("F15").Value = TotalAmountTXT.Value
Range("J7").Value = PatientNumberTXT.Value
Range("J9").Value = ClinicCBO.Value
Range("J11").Value = ProviderCBO.Value
Range("J13").Value = InitialsTXT.Value
Range("J15").Value = ReceiptTXT.Value
```

'Print receipt sheet

```
Range("A1:K16").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
Range("A20").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
Range("A1:K35").Select
Range("K35").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$K$35"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly -- I don't think there is a super straight forward way to do this.  Here's what I would recommend...

Here's a way to do it working in Excel.  I create a hidden sheet (sheet 3 is set to hidden) so that my users don't see it.  I use this code in the "print" button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'ALT+Printscreen to screen capture the form
    Application.SendKeys "%{1068}"

    'Paste on a hidden sheet
    Sheet3.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
    Sheet3.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A6")

    'Print hidden sheet.
    Sheet3.PrintOut
End Sub
```

Does that solve your problem?